# How do I pattern match on a generic with an abstract inner type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching

I'd like to apply `switch` statement pattern matching to determine if I'm dealing with a specific generic type. The inner type may be one of several that inherit from an abstract class. Here's an example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  abstract class Vehicle
  {
    public abstract string Name { get; }
  }

  internal class Sedan : Vehicle
  {
    public override string Name => "Sedan";
  }

  abstract class AbstractLoad
  {
    public abstract string Name { get; }
  }

  internal class Oil : AbstractLoad
  {
    public override string Name => "Oil";
  }

  internal class Lumber : AbstractLoad
  {
    public override string Name => "Lumber";
  }

  class Semi<TLoad> : Vehicle where TLoad : AbstractLoad
  {
    public override string Name => "Semi";

    public TLoad Load { get; set; }
  }
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var vehicle = new Semi<Oil> {Load = new Oil()};

      DescribeVehicle(vehicle);
    }

    static void DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
      switch (vehicle)
      {
        case Sedan sedan:
          Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a sedan");
          break;
        case Semi<AbstractLoad> semi:
          Console.WriteLine($"This vehicle is a semi carrying {semi.Load.Name}");
          break;
        default:
          Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like it to print, "This vehicle is a semi carrying Oil". However, it prints, "We don't know what kind of vehicle this is." Is there some way I can get it to match the `Semi` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what the type information for `vehicle` contains: `vehicle` *is* indeed a `ConsoleApp1.Semi<ConsoleApp1.Oil>` and not a `ConsoleApp1.Semi<ConsoleApp1.AbstractLoad>`, right? That's why the type doesn't match.

You have several possibilities here:

1. You can obviously use multiple `case` branches, each with exact types, but it's bad style because it defeats the purpose and makes you write a lot of duplicate code, and there's a high risk of forgetting to add the new branch when you create a new sub-class of `AbstractLoad`. Do this only if you *really* have no other choice, but it should give you massive headache whenever you need this. Avoid it if possible, it's bad style. No, really.

```
// === DISCLAIMER ===
// Just for illustrative purposes.
// Don't use this solution, it's bad style.

using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }
    }

    internal class Sedan : Vehicle
    {
        public override string Name => "Sedan";
    }

    abstract class AbstractLoad
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }
    }

    internal class Oil : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Oil";
    }

    internal class Lumber : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Lumber";
    }

    class Semi<TLoad> : Vehicle where TLoad : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Semi";

        public TLoad Load { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var vehicle = new Semi<Oil> { Load = new Oil() };

            DescribeVehicle(vehicle);
        }

        static void DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
            switch (vehicle) {
                case Sedan _:
                    Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a sedan");
                    break;
                case Semi<Oil> _:
                    Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a semi carrying Oil.");
                    break;
                case Semi<Lumber> _:
                    Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a semi carrying Lumber.");
                    break;
                // Add new cases here (but rather don't use this solution at all)
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Instead of using one `DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)` method with a switch, you can create a second `DescribeVehicle<TLoad>(Semi<TLoad> semi) where TLoad : AbstractLoad` method. This is a moderate duplication of code, and less dangerous, but still not super-pretty.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }
    }

    internal class Sedan : Vehicle
    {
        public override string Name => "Sedan";
    }

    abstract class AbstractLoad
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }
    }

    internal class Oil : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Oil";
    }

    internal class Lumber : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Lumber";
    }

    class Semi<TLoad> : Vehicle where TLoad : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Semi";

        public TLoad Load { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var vehicle = new Semi<Oil> { Load = new Oil() };

            DescribeVehicle(vehicle);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
            switch (vehicle) {
                case Sedan _:
                    Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a sedan");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void DescribeVehicle<TLoad>(Semi<TLoad> semi) where TLoad : AbstractLoad {
            Console.WriteLine($"This vehicle is a semi carrying {semi.Load.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

The real deal is that your approach of using an independent `static` function with a `switch` statement is already part of the problem:

3. Since you're already using inheritance, use the `ToString()` method. Override it in the `Sedan` or `Semi<TLoad>` class with the output you want, and ideally do the same for the `Oil`/`Lumber` etc. classes. Or, if you need `ToString()` for something else, then create your own abstract base method `string Describe()` in `Vehicle` and `AbstractLoad` and override that in `Sedan`/`Oil` etc.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }

        public override string ToString() => $"This vehicle is a {Name}.";

        // To keep the output identical to your example, use this method

        // public override string ToString() => $"We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.";

        // You then have to override ToString in Sedan, too. But I think there's no reason
        // why you'd want to have to override ToString everywhere with the same code.
    }

    internal class Sedan : Vehicle
    {
        public override string Name => "Sedan";
    }

    abstract class AbstractLoad
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }

        public override string ToString() => Name;
    }

    internal class Oil : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Oil";
    }

    internal class Lumber : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Lumber";
    }

    class Semi<TLoad> : Vehicle where TLoad : AbstractLoad
    {
        public override string Name => "Semi";

        public TLoad Load { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => $"This vehicle is a semi carrying {Load}.";
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var vehicle = new Semi<Oil> { Load = new Oil() };

            DescribeVehicle(vehicle);
        }

        static void DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
            Console.WriteLine(vehicle.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that #3 is the best approach in this case. I was trying to make a model of a much more complex situation where #3 doesn't work as well. However, #2 should work in the complex situation as well. Regardless, #2 and #3 are great solutions to the problem I posed.

Comment: @watkipet I'd really like to know which complex situation cannot be solved using #3, because virtual methods are obviously the most accurate type switches you can have.

Comment: @LWChris: the #3 is great! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @LWChris: I guess, we can make the #3 solution even better using ``this.GetType().Name`` like ``public override string Name => this.GetType().Name;`` Or, is it a bad idea?

Comment: If anything, I'd go with `nameof(Oil)` etc. as method bodies for the getter implementations, because that's a constant expression instead of actual code. However, I think that's only suitable in this example, because pretty soon you'll run into cases like `GreasyOil` or `AppleCider` where you'd probably like to have "prettier" names than type names.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I like the second solution from LWChris

It does work well:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vehicle = new Semi<Oil> { Load = new Oil() };
        DescribeVehicle<Oil>(vehicle);
    }

    static void DescribeVehicle<TLoad>(Semi<TLoad> vehicle) where TLoad : AbstractLoad
    {
        switch (vehicle)
        {
            case Sedan _:
                Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a sedan");
                break;

            case Semi<TLoad> semi:
                Console.WriteLine($"This vehicle is a semi carrying {semi.Load.Name}");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**=== 8< ======================= previous version ======================= 8< ===**

I guess, you have to use `AbstractLoad` as inner type, since Semi is not directly the same type as Semi:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vehicle = new Semi<AbstractLoad> { Load = new Oil() };

            DescribeVehicle(vehicle);
        }

        static void DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
        {
            switch (vehicle)
            {
                case Sedan _:
                    Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a sedan");
                    break;

                case Semi<AbstractLoad> semi:
                    Console.WriteLine($"This vehicle is a semi carrying {semi.Load.Name}");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This version works.

Comment: Yes, but does that really solve the problem at hand? In this case, you'd not need the generic at all, and the `Load` property getter will be utterly useless.

Comment: He wanted to match it, so it does work. But you are right, this is definitely not the best solution. :-)

Comment: But what if the vehicle happens to be a Sedan? Then the version with the abstract DescribeVehicle method wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Sure, you need here to have both methods. I thought it's clear.

Comment: Yes, you'll need both methods, and the `Sedan` case in the `Describe<TLoad>` method makes no sense, you'll never reach it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2.** *(suggested by LWChris)*

Version with both methods:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/3yVevr

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vehicle = new Semi<Oil> { Load = new Oil() };
        DescribeVehicle(vehicle);
        var sedan = new Sedan();
        DescribeVehicle(sedan);
    }

    static void DescribeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        switch (vehicle)
        {
            case Sedan _:
                Console.WriteLine("This vehicle is a sedan");
                break;

            case Semi<AbstractLoad> semi:
                Console.WriteLine($"This vehicle is a semi carrying {semi.Load.Name}");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
                break;
        }
    }

    static void DescribeVehicle<TLoad>(Semi<TLoad> vehicle) where TLoad : AbstractLoad
    {
        switch (vehicle)
        {
            case Semi<TLoad> semi:
                Console.WriteLine($"This vehicle is a semi carrying {semi.Load.Name}");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("We don't know what kind of vehicle this is.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Semi<AbstractLoad>` case in the `DescribeVehicle` method will never be reached because every call with a `Semi<AbstractLoad>` will be resolved to `DescribeVehicle<TLoad>`. `DescribeVehicle<TLoad>` doesn't need a case switch at all, you're checking against the type that was already required in the signature.